# SEDA v/s SAGA pattern

Tags: microservices

What is the actual difference between SAGA design and SEDA (Staged event driven) design? Mostly the search I did, points to example of SAGA usage between micro services and SEDA example generally points to dividing  event processing into multiple stages. SEDA does not talk about  usage between two micro services or between components in same micro services.  If I think of SEDA stage processing where messages are exchanged between component via queue, then I could think of SEDA is generic version of SAGA whereas SAGA talks about how to achieve event processing between micro services. SAGA also used to implement local transaction when business process involves across multiple micro services with the help of events. I am interested to know your thoughts on these patterns

Comment: I've just heard of SEDA and I can't see a difference between it and SAGA...
As you just said, it feels like SEDA is a generic idea of SAGA